# How do I capture AWS Backup failures in terraform when Windows VSS fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-backup, opsgenie

I'm using AWS Backups to back up several EC2 instances. I have terraform that seems to report correctly when there is a backup failure, but I am also interested in when the disks have backed up correctly, but when Windows VSS fails. Ultimately, the failed events are going to be published to Opsgenie. Is there a way to accomplish this? I have tried capturing all events with the 'aws_backup_vault_notifications' resource, and I have tried a filter as described in this AWS blog: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-backup-failed-job-notification/

I have included most of my terraform below, minus the opsgenie module; I can get successful or fully failing events published to Opsgenie just fine if I include those events:

```
locals {
  backup_vault_events = toset(["BACKUP_JOB_FAILED", "COPY_JOB_FAILED"])
}

resource "aws_backup_region_settings" "legacy" {
  resource_type_opt_in_preference = {
    "Aurora"          = false
    "DynamoDB"        = false
    "EFS"             = false
    "FSx"             = false
    "RDS"             = false
    "Storage Gateway" = false
    "EBS"             = true
    "EC2"             = true
    "DocumentDB"      = false
    "Neptune"         = false
    "VirtualMachine"  = false
  }
}

resource "aws_backup_vault" "legacy" {
  name        = "Legacy${var.environment_tag}"
  kms_key_arn = aws_kms_key.key.arn

}

resource "aws_iam_role" "legacy_backup" {
  name                 = "AWSBackupService"
  permissions_boundary = data.aws_iam_policy.role_permissions_boundary.arn
  assume_role_policy   = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"],
      "Effect": "allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["backup.amazonaws.com"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "legacy_backup" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup"
  role       = aws_iam_role.legacy_backup.name
}

###############################################################################
## Second Region Backup
###############################################################################

resource "aws_backup_vault" "secondary" {
  provider    = aws.secondary
  name        = "Legacy${var.environment_tag}SecondaryRegion"
  kms_key_arn = aws_kms_replica_key.secondary_region.arn

  tags = merge(
    local.tags, {
      name = "Legacy${var.environment_tag}SecondaryRegion"
    }
  )
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "backups" {
  policy_id = "__default_policy_ID"

  statement {
    actions = [
      "SNS:Publish",
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["backup.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    resources = [
      aws_sns_topic.backup_alerts.arn
    ]

    sid = "__default_statement_ID"
  }
}

###############################################################################
# SNS
###############################################################################
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "backup_alerts" {
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.backup_alerts.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.backups.json
}

resource "aws_backup_vault_notifications" "backup_alerts" {
  backup_vault_name   = aws_backup_vault.legacy.id
  sns_topic_arn       = aws_sns_topic.backup_alerts.arn
  backup_vault_events = local.backup_vault_events
}


resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "backup_alerts_opsgenie_target" {
  topic_arn                       = aws_sns_topic.backup_alerts.arn
  protocol                        = "https"
  endpoint                        = module.opsgenie_team.sns_integration_sns_endpoint
  confirmation_timeout_in_minutes = 1
  endpoint_auto_confirms          = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at doing a lambda subscription for the sns topic, and then you can process the message in the lambda. Once the message gets processed you can put what you need right to opsgenie.

I've got a generic emailer that I wrote that is tied to sqs and all email gets processed off of that, so when a job finishes the lambda fires puts the status and any details I want in the sqs queue. This way all of it's logged etc.